# How to access the child' state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It's me again,

I have this code :

```
/* App.js */

class App extends Component {

    state = {
        active1: true,
        active2: false,
        active3: false,
        active4: false,
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.active1) {
            return(
                <div className="wrapper">
                    <Header />
                </div>
            )
        } else if (this.state.active2) {
            return(
                <div className="wrapper">
                    <Header />
                </div>
            )
        } else if (this.state.active3) {
            return(
                <div className="wrapper">
                    <Header />
                </div>
            )
        } else if (this.state.active4) {
            return(
                <div className="wrapper">
                    <Header />
                </div>
            )
        }

        return(
            <div className="wrapper">
                <Header />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

As you see I have `<Header />` Component which is in 'Header.js' :

```
/* Header.js */

class Header extends Component {

    state = {
        active1: true,
        active2: false,
        active3: false,
        active4: false,
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <header className="container">
                    <button className="buttonName" onClick={() => {
                        this.setState({
                            active1: true,
                            active2: false,
                            active3: false,
                            active4: false,
                        })
                    }}>Accueil</button>
                    <button className="buttonName" onClick={() => {
                        this.setState({
                            active1: false,
                            active2: true,
                            active3: false,
                            active4: false,
                        })
                    }}>Portfolio</button>
                    <button className="buttonName" onClick={() => {
                        this.setState({
                            active1: false,
                            active2: false,
                            active3: true,
                            active4: false,
                        })
                    }}>Curriculum</button>
                    <button className="buttonName" onClick={() => {
                        this.setState({
                            active1: false,
                            active2: false,
                            active3: false,
                            active4: true,
                        })
                    }}>Tarifs</button>
            </header>
        )
    }
}
```

And I saw something on React DevTools : this.setState() changes the state of `<Header />` and not the state of `<App />.`

So here is my question : how can I access the `<Header />` state to apply a condition on it. Because here this code is not functionning :

I can't write this :

```
if (Header.state.active1) {//Do something}
```

because it throws an error.

So do you know something to do the same ?

Comment: You can't access child state from the parent component. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: To access Header state in App component you need to know about callbacks in react. Read about callbacks in react. With callbacks you can get child state in parent

Comment: My program works when I put the content of 'Header.js' but the code is very big. So I want to put all this code in another file (Header.js) instead of writing the whole code in App.js.

Comment: You can pass a callback function to the header component. You can call it and define and pass in for example the id of the clicked header. This callback then set's your state directly in App.js rather then in Header.js. 
What you are trying to achieve seems to me a good fit for "React Router" . I recommend checking it out. It does all this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I think you are doing some overengineering here. I imagine you are trying to do something like that.

```js
const menu = [
  { label: 'Item 1', id: 1 },
  { label: 'Item 2', id: 2 },
  { label: 'Item 3', id: 3 },
  { label: 'Item 4', id: 4 },
];

class Header extends React.Component {
  render () {
    const { items, setActive, active } = this.props;
    
    return (
      <header>
        {
           items.map(item => (
            <button
              className={active === item.id ? 'active': ''}
              key={item.id}
              onClick={() => setActive(item.id)}
            >
              {item.label}
            </button>
           ))
        }
      </header>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    active: 1,
  };
  
  setActive = (id) => {
    this.setState({ active: id });
  }
  
  render() {
    return(
      <Header
        items={menu}
        active={this.state.active}
        setActive={(id) => this.setActive(id)}
      />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
.active {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```